# How to map row elements to column after doing intersection?

Tags: r

This was a previous question I asked I nearly have the solution provided by stack community

My dummy dataframe

```
df1 = data.frame(genes = c('gene1', 'gene3', 'gene4', 'gene2','gene11'))
df2 = data.frame(genes = c('gene3', 'gene2', 'gene5', 'gene1', "genet",'gene11'))
df3 = data.frame(genes = c('gene6', 'gene3', 'gene4', 'gdene7','gene11', 'genex', "gene10"))
dfList <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

To see if my set of genes are present in each dataframe or not I ran this

```
dfList %>% 
  bind_rows(.id="df") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=df, names_prefix="df", values_from=df)
```

Which gives something like this

```
genes   df1 df2 df3
<chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>
gene1   1   2   NA
gene3   1   2   3
gene4   1   NA  3
gene2   1   2   NA
gene11  1   2   3
gene5   NA  2   NA
genet   NA  2   NA
gene6   NA  NA  3
gdene7  NA  NA  3
genex   NA  NA  3
gene10  NA  NA  3
```

In the above dataframe I can see for each gene, whether or not that gene is in `df1`, `df2`, or `df3`. The problem I have is to find genes based on their presence and absence in different columns/condition

The below code as suggested to do what Im trying to do.

```
dfList %>% 
  bind_rows(.id="df") %>% 
  group_by(genes) %>% 
  summarise(minDF=min(df), maxDF=max(df)) %>% 
  filter(minDF == maxDF & maxDF == 3) %>% 
  pull(genes)

'gdene7''gene10''gene6''genex'
```

It identifies genes, in this example, that are only present in `df3`. How do I identify genes that are, for example:

- present in all three frames?
- present in two specified frames, say `df1` and `df2`
- present only in one frame, say `df2`?

Any help or suggestion would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options here

1. You can modify your `pivot_longer()` call to include the `value_fn` param to make logical vectors, and then use `rowwise()`, and use `any` or `all`. For example, if you want to get the genes that are in df1, df2, and df3, you can do this:

```
dfList %>% 
  bind_rows(.id="df") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=df, names_prefix="df", values_from=df,values_fn = \(x) !is.na(x)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(all(df1,df2,df3)) %>% 
  pull(genes)

[1] "gene3"  "gene11"
```

If you change the `filter(all())` line to `filter(all(df1,df2))`, this will give you the genes in both df1 and df2, without regard to df3

```
[1] "gene1"  "gene3"  "gene2"  "gene11"
```

2. However, you don't need these intermediate steps. Instead, you can use this flexible function below, called `find_genes()`, which takes a function `f`, such as `intersect`, `union`, or `setdiff`, and any number of dfs, and returns the set of genes across those dfs according to the set-function requested

```
find_genes <- function(f,...) {
  Reduce(f,c(...))
}
```

Now, if you want to know the genes only in df3, and not in any others, do this:

```
find_genes(setdiff,df3,df2,df1)
```

Output:

```
[1] "gene6"  "gdene7" "genex"  "gene10"
```

If you want to know genes that are present in both df1 and df2, pass `intersect` to the `find_genes()` function, like this:

```
find_genes(intersect, df1,df2)
```

Output:

```
[1] "gene1"  "gene3"  "gene2"  "gene11"
```

If you want to know genes that are present in all three, pass all three frames

```
find_genes(intersect, df3, df2, df1)
```

Output:

```
[1] "gene3"  "gene11"
```

If you want the union of genes in two frames, pass `union`:

```
find_genes(union, df1, df3)
```

Output:

```
 "gene1"  "gene3"  "gene4"  "gene2"  "gene11" "gene6"  "gdene7" "genex"  "gene10"
```

Comment: Can I dput to show you my orginal data frame? Thank you for correcting my question which I now more clear even to me as well

Comment: When I run the first solution I get this error `Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:3:76: unexpected input
2:   bind_rows(.id="df") %>% 
3:   pivot_wider(names_from=df, names_prefix="df", values_from=df,values_fn = \
                                                                              ^
Traceback:`

Comment: perhaps replace `\(x)` with `function(x)` if you have R version<4.1

Comment: that is a life saver I ran the code like 20 times clearing my workspace time and again..thank you...my version R 4.0.3

Comment: perhaps it's time to update if you can.. :)

Comment: well I thought of quite a number of times but I had done many stuffs in earlier version and Now I don't want to dig my time in fixing R things which as self taught programmer really hard for me.I will once all my paper work is finished ..